# Can Windows application crash dumps contain personally identifiable information?

Tags: windows

I'm referring to the program crash dumps in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\CrashDumps`, not the Windows' own. The latest dump files on my system are all over 30 MB (+50 000 lines) and I can't even inspect them in a text editor. Sometimes it's required to send the files over when contacting a support department — can I be sure that no data outside of my interactions with the program in question are shared?

Comment: That location is for application crashes, not Windows crashes which contain much more personal information.

Answer (score -1):

Crash dumps may certainly contain personally identifiable information.

For example, if you’re in the middle of entering your credit card
number when the program you’re working-in crashes, chances are that the credit
card number, or some portion of it, is likely to be inside that crash dump.

The crash dump may also contain memory segments of Windows system tables
and executing programs, which may include user-names and passwords
and certificates.
Worse, if a program has read some encrypted and highly secure data from the disk,
this data may exist in unencrypted plain-text format in its dumped memory.

Comment: I can't upvote yet — sorry.

Comment: You can accept any answer on your own post by clicking its V icon, and may also in the future transfer  acceptance to another answer in the same way.